# Create a file for each name in variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am currently trying to do something in Ansible
I currently have a variable

```yaml
this_directories:
  - { name: "derp", path: "/var/log/derp" }
  - { name: "memes", path: "/var/lib/memes/containers" }
  - { name: "docker", path: "/var/lib/docker" }
  - { name: "lib", path: "/var/lib" }
```

I want to create a multiple files with content for each name in `this_directories`

so make a new file

```
derp
memes
docker
lib
```

I tried a task like this

```yaml
- copy:
    dest: "/etc/{{ this_directories.name }}"
    content: |
      {{this_directories}} {
      rotate 12
      size 10M
      weekly
      compress
      missingok
      notifempty
      copytuncate
      }
```

But I don't think this is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-list-of-hashes) to iterate over your list of hashes:

```yaml
- copy:
    dest: "/etc/{{ item.name }}"
    content: |
      {{ item.path }} {
      rotate 12
      size 10M
      weekly
      compress
      missingok
      notifempty
      copytuncate
      }
  loop: "{{ this_directories }}"
```